# tcpdf - indentation issue after line break

Tags: html, css, tcpdf

Do you know how to align the text after a line break with tcpdf?

Using tcpdf 6.2.13, and the writeHTML method.
I'm trying to have perfectly left aligned text, but every time the line is too long, the next line is offset to the left, see the picture and code below.

[image]

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
    <tr>
        <td>
            My Company Equipement<br>
            France
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="green" cellpadding="0">
            <b>Addresse de livraison</b>
            <br>
            <br>
            Team Adamon FIGHTING ACADEMY
            38 chemin de Tomasenea<br>
            Zone de Berrouetta<br>
            26000 URRUGNE<br>
            France
        </td>
        <td align="left" style="margin:0;padding:0;text-indent: 0;">
            <b>Addresse de livraison</b>
            <br>
            <br>
            Team Adamon FIGHTING ACADEMY
            38 chemin de Tomasenea<br>
            Zone de Berrouetta<br>
            26000 URRUGNE<br>
            France
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>
    Team Adamon FIGHTING ACADEMY
    Team Adamon FIGHTING ACADEMY
    Team Adamon FIGHTING ACADEMY
    Team Adamon FIGHTING ACADEMY
    <br>
    Team Adamon FIGHTING ACADEMY<br>
    Team Adamon FIGHTING ACADEMY<br>
</p>
```

I know I could count the number of words and put some <br> tags,
but do you know a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems that TCPDF shows the whitespace.

```
<td>
     Line 
</td>
```

will have this undesired indentation, while

```
<td>Line 
</td>
```

won't. Also remove whitespace after `<br />` tags. Same goes to whitespace between the opening `<p>` and its contents.

**EDIT:** Removed previous suggestions about switching to [writeHTMLCell()](https://tcpdf.org/docs/source_docs/classTCPDF/#a8458280d15b73d3baffb28eebe2d9246), using [writeHTML()](https://tcpdf.org/docs/source_docs/classTCPDF/#ac3fdf25fcd36f1dce04f92187c621407)  `$cell` parameter set to `true` and removing the cellpadding.

Comment: I tried cellpadding="0", and also the $cell parameter to true: it didn't change anything. I "can't" use the writeHTMLCell technique due to some other constraints I have, but I gave it a quick try and it didn't work either.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Got to the work PC and checked, nothing of what I suggested works. Have to dig a bit now, interesting bug. I definitely have a table in writeHTMLCell which displays for some years without this bug in two different versions of TCPDF.

Comment: Edited the answer. Tried removing the whitespace between opening tags and content, this helped on your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same issue yesterday.

As @Matvey Andreyev said, TCPDF does make a difference between

```
<td>
foo
<td>
```

and

```
<td>foo</td>
```

a workaround would be to wrap your `td` value in a `<div>` this would force the lines to start with the same indentation

the following should work

```
<td><div>first line<br />second line<br /> third line</div></td>
```

Comment: Tried wrapping in a `<div>`. Still needs whitespace removal. If a div contains `<br>[whitespace]`, then the line following this `<br>` will look indented from the div edge. TCPDF v6.2.9